# Is this local or static variable capture?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, static

In the following code, the lambda expressions capture a `static` variable. 
However, it is also *local* to the scope of the enclosing class, so would this be local variable capture or static variable capture?

```
public class ExampleImpl{
    static String someStaticVar = "text";
    Example lam = () -> {
        System.out.println(someStaticVar);
    };


    interface Example {
        void sample();
    }
}
```

Comment: In my understanding, this would be a local variable capture, only if the variable `someStaticVar` is effectively final in the context.

Comment: @Naman the lambda would have to be local too(in e.g. a function scope)

Comment: Where do these terms “local variable capture” and “static variable capture” come from? How are they defined? In what regard does this distinction matter?

Comment: @Holger I went searching these terms after reading the question and one of the links I ended up with was http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/lambda-expressions.html#variable-capture , the other search suggestions definitely ended up with lambdas and relevant variable details but without those exact terms.

Comment: I also wonder _why_ would this matter, at all, to you.

Comment: 'Local' means 'method-local. `someStaticVar` is not method-local, but it is `static`.

Answer (score 1):

The terms “local variable capture” and “static variable capture” do not appear anywhere in the specification, so their meaning would be up to whoever coined these terms.

The most likely interpretation is that “local variable capture” just mean “capture of a local variable” and likewise “static variable capture” means “capture of a static variable”, in other words, capture of a variable which happens to be of either kind, local, instance field, or static field, and then, the answer is quiet simple, the nature of the variables doesn’t change when you place a lambda expression in a different scope.

In your example, `someStaticVar` always is a `static` variable, regardless of where you access it.

It’s not clear why this distinction matters to you. There might be technical differences under the hood, which are intentionally unspecified, hence, implementation specific. The most relevant aspect of the type of the captured variables would be that capturing an instance variable will cause the generated instance to keep a reference to the instance. But first, this doesn’t apply to local variables or static variables, second, this is a natural relationship, that code potentially accessing an instance field may prevent the garbage collection of that instance.